# catkin_make , when i try to create in ubuntu 18 it shows error

Tags: ros

```
ImportError: "from catkin_pkg.package import parse_package" failed: No module named 'catkin_pkg'
Make sure that you have installed "catkin_pkg", it is up to date and on the PYTHONPATH.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/usr/bin/python3
  "/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py"
  "/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml"
  "/home/akash/catkin_ws/build/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake")
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:74 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:168 (_catkin_package_xml)
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:58 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/akash/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/akash/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:320: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

This was the error i am getting and i am very new to ros. i dont know even how to describe this error.

Comment: "Make sure that you have installed "catkin_pkg", it is up to date and on the PYTHONPATH" Either you did not correctly install ROS, or your installation is corrupt  or incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out the answer . What i understood is the catkin_make should able to access python3. So i tried to install catkin_pkg using

```
pip install catkin_pkg.
```

But i got a error of

```
pip not found but can be installed with sudo
```

So then i installed python 3 pip using

```
 sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Then i has access to install pip in terminal.so i installed catkin_pkg using

```
pip3 install catkin_pkg
```

So then when i try to run catkin_make it runs successfully.

But i couldnot figured how this all worked magically can someone explain me